# 既に回答の付いた質問も、内容が明確でなければクローズすべき？

Tags: 討議, 質問のクローズ

「問題点をより明確にする必要がある」または「焦点を絞る必要がある」と思われる質問に対しても、詳しいユーザーが分かる範囲で回答を付けているケースがあります。

しかし、回答に前後して質問にクローズ票が入れられたり、実際にクローズされてしまうケースも時折見受けられます。

このようなケースはどのように扱うべきでしょうか。

(例)

- クローズは "回答を投稿するための前提条件を明確にするため" なので、回答が付いた時点で
  **敢えてクローズする必要はない**
- "ナレッジの蓄積" という観点で言えば、回答が付いていようと質問も見直してもらうために
  **いったんクローズすべき**

Answer (score 3):

クローズ票を投じて OK です。

既に回答がついていたり、質問者さんにとっては解決した質問であったりしても、後々回答が集まるかもしれません。もし質問が曖昧なものであれば、どんどん集まる多様な回答に対しどれが "良い" 回答なのか決めきれず、回答への投票の意味が薄れてしまうでしょう。単に回答が集まるというだけでは、良い Q&A を作っているとは言えません。どの回答が質問を解決しているのか客観的に判断できるように改善を繰り返していくべきです。

スタック・オーバーフローは長期的には知識を蓄積することを目的としています。質問者さん個人の問題のみを解決しようとしているわけではありません。長期的に見れば、質問の内容を明確化しておく意義があります。

ですから既に回答がついているかいないかには関わらず、質問が曖昧であるならばそれはクローズの理由になります。問題を解決するためにより多くの情報が必要なら、クローズ票を入れたり改善を促すコメントをしたりすべきです。

もし質問と回答のやり取りの中で質問が明確化されたなら、そのことを質問文に反映しましょう。そうすれば内容が曖昧だという理由でのクローズを避けられるでしょう。